# Deploying Docker images using Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

After reviewing this amazing forum, i thought it's time to join in...

I'm having issue with a playbook that deploys multiple Dockers.

- My **Ansible** version is: 2.5.1
- My **Python** version is 3.6.9
- My Linux Images are 18.04 from the site: **OSboxes**.

Docker service is installed and running on both of the machines.

According to this website, all you need to do is follow the instructions and everything will work perfectly. :)

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-deploy-a-container-with-ansible/

**(The playbook i use is in the link above)**

but after following the steps, and using the playbook, i've got this error.

```
TASK [Pull default Docker image] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.38]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: source Supported parameters include: api_version, archive_path, buildargs, cacert_path, cert_path, container_limits, debug, docker_host, dockerfile, filter_logger, force, http_timeout, key_path, load_path, name, nocache, path, pull, push, repository, rm, ssl_version, state, tag, timeout, tls, tls_hostname, tls_verify, use_tls"}
```

I'll be happy for your support on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got this playbook to sing! :)

I did the following.

1. upgraded the Ansibe version, so now it's running on version: 2.9.15.
2. my python3 version is:3.6.9

After upgrading the Ansible to the version i've mentioned above, i got and error message: Failed to import the required python library (Docker SDK for Python (python >==2.7) or docker-py (python 2.6)) on *osboxes*(this is my machine) python...

so, after Googling this error, i found this URL:

**https://neutrollized.blogspot.com/2018/12/cannot-have-both-docker-py-and-docker.html**

SO, i decided to remove the docker from my machines, including the python that was installed using pip (i used the command pip-list to see if there is docker installed, and remove it using: pip uninstall).

After removing the Docker from my machines, i added the playbook one more play. install docker-compose (that's what solve my problem, and it took care of the python versions).

Just follow the URL i attached in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `source: pull` option was added in [Ansible 2.8](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/docker_image_module.html). Since you are using Ansible 2.5.1, that option is not available.

You can either use a later version, 2.8 or above, or just remove that line from your playbook and it should work:

```
- name: Pull default Docker image
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ default_container_image }}"
```

You won't have the guarantee that the image has been newly pulled from a registry. If that's important in your case, you can remove any locally cached version of the image first:

```
- name: Remove Docker image
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ default_container_image }}"
    state: absent

- name: Pull default Docker image
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ default_container_image }}"
```

Comment: Thanks your answer.

i'll do a google search on how to upgrade my Ansible to the version you've mentioned, and hopefully this will solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the [doc of `docker_image`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/docker_image_module.html#docker-image-module) module of Ansible 2.5, there is indeed no parameter `source`.

Nevertheless, the [doc of version 2.9](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/docker_image_module.html?highlight=docker) tells us it has been "added in 2.8"! So you have to update you Ansible version to be able to run the linked playbook as-is. That's you best option.

Otherwise, another option would be to keep your version 2.5 and simply remove the line 38.

```
(-)        source: pull
```

But I don't know how was the default behaviour before 2.8, so I cannot garanty you that it will do what you expect!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering my post. i'll upgrade Ansible and report back.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering my post. i'll upgrade Ansible and report back. (i wonder which version he used in the video...:)